# C# Library for manipulating Excel Files?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, vba

I'm working on a project to migrate excel data into new excel files that are compatible with another system. As part of this work, I have to do a lot of data manipulation between excel sheets (concatenation, text matching, text manipulation, etc).

I have been writing VBA scripts but I find the language a bit difficult to work with when errors start popping up. I'd prefer to use C# in Visual Studio since I'm already familiar with the language/IDE.

Would Epplus or the Microsoft Interop libraries be a more modern way to do this work? I'm interested in using a modern API that's intuitive if you already have experience with C++/C#.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501528/openxml-libraries-alternatives-to-closedxml

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573073/what-is-the-common-knowledge-about-npoi-epplus-and-koogra-as-of-2015

Answer (score 1):

You can have a check on [Spire.XLS for .NET](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/excel-for-net-introduce.html) library.

Spire.XLS for .NET is a feature rich Excel library written in C#, it does not have any dependency on MS Office and can be easily applied to create, convert, edit and print excel files, merge excel files, search text, create chart, import/export data and many more within .NET applications.

For more supported features, you can check this [online documentation](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide-Content.html).